# Kendo Grid Issue

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I am using `kendo grid`, with `angularjs`. The following is my grid columns, declared as the same as below-

```
this.$scope.gridColumn = [
            {
                field: 'IsActive', width: 65, editable: true, filterable: false,
                template: '< md-checkbox aria-label="Checkbox2" ng-model="dataItem.IsActive" ng-change="select(dataItem)" ></md-checkbox>'
            },
            {
                ...
            }];
```

I am trying to incorporate a "Select All" checkbox. But unfortunately, the "headerTemplate" tag is showing the following error -

> Error: ngTransclude:orphan 
>   
> Orphan ngTransclude Directive

Please help me to sort it out.

Thanks